# Regex which allows 3 digit before precision and 2 digits after precision

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, regex, scripting

I have written a Regex which will take only integers but I need to rewrite this regex to only allow 3 digit before precision and 2 digits after precision

How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it must always have 3 digits, a decimal point, and 2 digits, e.g., `412.88`, then:

```
/^\d{3}\.\d{2}$/
```

If it can be *up to* 3 digits before and *up to* 2 after (possibly no decimal point at all) then maybe something like:

```
/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

In **c#**

`@"^\d{3}\.\d{2}$"`

```
//in c# we need to use verbatim string `@""` to treat escape sequences as normal literals instead of giving it a special meaning..
```

In **javascript**

`/^\d{3}\.\d{2}$/`

Comment: Verbatim strings don't silence the compiler. They cause backslashes to be treated literally, not as escape characters.

Comment: @TimPietzcker in a way they do cuz dey dnt complain after using it..invalid escape sequence like like \d,\w are treated as an `error` by the compiler.